# Route Azure point-to-site traffic to on-premise network via site-to-site connection

Tags: vpn, azure, azure-networking

In Azure, I have the following:

- Virtual network: 172.16.0.0/20
- Site-to-site VPN between Azure and on-premise network
- Point-to-site VPN for workstations to connect to the Azure vnet (172.16.254.0/24)

The site-to-site VPN is working and I can access resources in both directions
i.e. on-premise can ping/RDP a VM in the Azure vnet
and the Azure VM can ping/RDP to on-premise servers

The Azure point-to-site VPN successfully connects and I can access the VM in the Azure vnet.
However, I am unable to ping/access resources within the on-premise network (192.168.0.0/22 - ideally routed via the site-to-site vpn).

- Is this possible?
- If so, any advice on how to make this work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Jeroen, that pointed me in the right direction.

To resolve this, I had to:

a) On the VPN client PC (Azure VPN client), manually add an entry in the %AppData%\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Cm\yourGuid\routes.txt

- ADD 192.168.0.0 MASK 255.255.252.0 default METRIC default IF default

b) Adjust the on-premise site-to-site routing to include the Azure P2S subnet (172.16.254.0/24)

Answer (score 1):

You almost give the answer. There can be two options.

1. The IPSEC VPN end-point does not know which gateway the IP routing tables are directed to when you try to connect to the on premise 192.168.0.0/22 subnet. Try in cmd ROUTE PRINT after Dial-up VPN is made. Next tracert 192.168.0.30 and see where it stops to find a L3 subnet and there you are.
2. Firewall rules in your Azure public cloud.